# Could someone add k8s as a synonym of kubernetes?

Tags: support, status-completed

I tried to add a synonym, but only admins are allowed to do that.

Comment: Sure.  Also, doesn't it sound a bit too hippy? :P

Comment: The synonym makes a lot of sense but I don't understand why you went and edited a bunch of `kubernetes` tagged questions to change the tag to `k8s`? https://devops.stackexchange.com/posts/1783/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

The synonym of [k8s](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k8s) is now [kubernetes](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes)